# hadoop "Input path does not exist" looks local drive

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I have a problem with my hadoop program. I'm trying to read a file into the mappers but I always get an error telling me the file not exist.

the code is like:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    //String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    conf.set("mapreduce.job.queuename", "alpha");
    conf.setLong("mapreduce.task.timeout", 1000 * 60 * 60);
    conf.setDouble("mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps", 0.75);
    conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", "\t");
    job.setMapperClass(MapperCollector.class);
    // job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MetaDataReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/myuser/theData.csv"));

    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    Path outFolder = new Path("/user/myuser/outFolder/");
    if (hdfs.exists(outFolder)) {
        hdfs.delete(outFolder, true); //Delete existing Directory
    }
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outFolder);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

and it fails with the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/user/myuser/theData.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at myuser.mypackage.GenerateTrainingData.main(GenerateTrainingData.java:82)
```

The code was working before, but after rebooting the cluster it does not work. Moreover, I can do "hadoop df -cat /user/myuser/theData.csv" and it works perfectly.

I seems hadoop now is looking into the local disk, but the file is in the hdfs. I don't know why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is an idiot as I was, I was running:

```
java -jar mycode.jar
```

instead of

```
hadoop jar mycode.jar
```

after doing it correctly everything works perfectly.